# Servlets not available when webapp project name is ROOT Eclipse Juno Tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

When I create a webapp named ROOT, create a new servlet named Test in package com.companyName.Test mapped to /test with @WebServlet("/test") and access from localhost/test (or localhost/ROOT/test) I get a 404.
However, if the webapp project has a different name i.e. "someWebapp", I can access from localhost/someWebapp/test as expected.

For reasons I can not control the webapp project name must be ROOT, the Test servlet must map to /test, and I must use Juno and Tomcat 7.0.

Hint: Eclipse is not creating a web.xml (but this is not an issue if the web app has different name than ROOT). I wanna keep it that way and use the @WebServlet annotation instead. Any search to try to fix this assumes that web.xml is there.

Hint 2: Static resources like html works from the / path, only servlets return 404, for example localhost/htmltest.test.

Comment: ROOT has a special meaning as it is used as the default context. Can you share your server.xml and context.xml.

Comment: They are the default of apache-tomcat-7.0.27. I'm using a clean apache-tomcat-7.0.27 installation.

Comment: Go to your tomcat/webapps/directory and delete the ROOT application first and then try to redeploy through eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Juned Ahsan, but unfortunately that didn't worked.